# Gelfand map is topologically injective

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras, gelfand-representation

Let $A$ be a commutative Banach algebra and let 
$$G: A \rightarrow C_{0}(\text{Spec}(A))$$ be a topologically injective map.

Recall that the map $T: X \rightarrow Y$ is called topologically injective if there exists a positive $C > 0$ such that $||Tx|| \geq C ||x||$ for all $x \in X$. One can also show that the latter is equivalent to the definition in which 
$$T: X \rightarrow \text{im}(T)$$ is a homeomorphism (in fact, it is the original definition)

How to prove that the Gelfand map $G$ is topologicall injective if and only if there exists $C > 0$ such that for all $a \in A$
$$||a^{2} || \geq C ||a||^{2}$$

Comment: 1). you forgot a 'y'. 2). what are your thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spectral radius $r(a)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \|a^{2^n}\|^{\frac{1}{2^n}}\geq \lim_{n\to\infty} (C^n\|a\|^{2^n})^{\frac{1}{2^n}}=\|a\|$, thus $\|G(a)\|=r(a)=\|a\|$. So, $G$ is in fact an isometry.

Comment: Indeed, it turned out to be much easier than i had expected. The "only if" part can be proved, i guess, in the similar fashion: since $G$ is topologically injective, $||Gx|| \geq C ||x||$ which implies $r(x) \geq C ||x||$, whilst it's well-known that $r(x) \leq ||x^{n}||^{\frac{1}{n}}$ for any $n$, plugging the $n = 2$ into the last line yields $||x^{2}|| \geq C ||x||^{2}$